Hiding status and navigation bar in Qt Android app
I want to hide the status and navigation bar in Android when my application is running in foreground. I am using Qt6 and have only androidManifest.xml and no other Android related files added. Please suggest a way using which I can hide both status and navigation bar using Android manifest only.
I tried adding below line to Android Manifest and was able to hide the status bar but also want to disable the navigation bar
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Hide system bars for immersive mode "...Immersive mode helps users avoid accidental exits during a game and delivers an immersive experience for enjoying images, videos, and books. However, be mindful of how often users jump in and out of apps to check notifications, to conduct impromptu searches, or to take other actions...."
